# Change language in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I've translated the files in WooCommerce (.mo and .po with POEdit). How can I change the language?

I've even overwritten woothemes-en_GB.mo and woothemes-en_GB.po and the language didn't changed.

Someone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try to set the WPLANG in wp-config.php under root directory? take a look at [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate WordPress WooCommerce Language without usage of plugin you can follow steps as per [change language for WooCommerce](http://guruquest.net/question/how-to-translate-wordpress-woocommerce-language/%20?utm_source=StackOverflow&utm_medium=StackOverflow&utm_campaign=StackOverflow)

WooCommerce language can be changed without a usage of the plugin.

- Change WordPress Language
- Add WooCommerce translation files