# how can i change language of woocommerce pages such as checkout and add to cart?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

i want to change language of woo commerce  pages  and woo commerce words
i tried more plugin WooCommerce Multilingual but it give me error in installation because it is not free .
are there any other  solutions to change language ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change language in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591458/change-language-in-woocommerce)

Comment: Have you installed Wordpress for your local language?